# Is there a way to reset password with Firebase Auth INSIDE a flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Firebase Auth has a method to send a verification email so the user can reset his/her password. This link redirects the user to a website where the new password will be written and saved.

Is there a way to reset a user's password using flutter and firebase inapp? I mean, could I send a verification code through SMS or email that would be then typed into the app and the user would choose a new password all inside the app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to change a user's password directly through the API, the user will have to enter their current password in order to be able to update it.

If you use the Admin SDK however you can implement whatever flow you want, and [update the password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) at the end of the flow. But of course in that case it is up to you to ensure you do it securely.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using [custom email handlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) along with dynamic links to open them in your app. This might require a custom domain to do so. Once the user visits your application on the custom route/page, you can then use [applyActionCode method](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#open-link-in-app) to process the email action. Checkout my answer here for a detailed explanation on processing the email actions:

[How to build a custom Email action handler in Flutter for Firebase Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68832547/how-to-build-a-custom-email-action-handler-in-flutter-for-firebase-authenticatio)