# How to build a custom Email action handler in Flutter for Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am very new to web development and i am building a website with `Flutter`.
I am aware of the `Routing` / `Navigator` system.
I would like to know how can i create such page in `Flutter` to handle Firebase email actions :

```
https://example.com/usermgmt?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=ABC123&apiKey=AIzaSy...&lang=fr
```

I am following this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler).

It is stated here that:

> Firebase adds several query parameters to your action handler URL when it generates user management emails.

However i don't understand if it's up to me to build the full `url` in my `Flutter` `Routes` or simply provide the endpoint `/usermgmt` and Firebase is automatically adding the params ?

I have tried to build a page in my website that addresses : `https://example.com/usermgmt` and it's working, the page exists hosted in my website.
Now if i add the Firebase params, it returns a `404 not found`.

What should i do ?

EDIT : I have made the UI working, it doesn't return a `404 not found` anymore.
I have done this for those interrested :

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          Widget? authPage;
          if (settings.name != null) {
            var uriData = Uri.parse(settings.name!);
            //uriData.path will be the path and uriData.queryParameters will hold query-params values

            print("Param in query : " + uriData.queryParameters.toString());
            switch (uriData.path) {
              case '/auth':
                authPage = AuthHandlerPage();
                break;
            }
          }
          if (authPage != null) {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => authPage!);
          }
        },
```

I simply need to handle the links according to the params now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the email action, you need to fetch the `oobCode` from URL parameters and use `applyActionCode` method (`checkActionCode` can be used before `applyActionCode` to make sure the oobCode is valid, usually not required as `applyActionCode` will throw an error on getting an invalid code as well):

```dart
var actionCode = "" // Get from URL

try {
  await auth.checkActionCode(actionCode);
  await auth.applyActionCode(actionCode);

  // If successful, reload the user:
  auth.currentUser.reload();
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'invalid-action-code') {
    print('The code is invalid.');
  }
}
```

If you are using [dynamic links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links), you can get it this way:

```dart
//Get actionCode from the dynamicLink
final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;
var actionCode = deepLink.queryParameters['oobCode'];
```

You can refer the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#open-link-in-app) for more information.

Alternatively, you can also use the [Firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-confirm-email-verification) to verify the email links if you need to verify the oobCode from a Cloud function or server.